# Using syslog in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, syslog

I am thinking of using syslog in my rails applications. The process is outlined in [this blog post](http://bowerstudios.com/node/688):

1. Add `gem 'SyslogLogger'` to your `Gemfile`
2. Add `require 'syslog_logger'` to the top of `config/environments/production.rb`
3. Also uncomment the `config.logger =` line in the same file.

In production box I have 4 rails applications running using passenger. If I switch to use syslogger for all 4 of my applications then I am afraid that the log messages from all 4 applications will go to a single file and the log messages will be interleaving. Of course, I can use splunk but first I wanted to check if it was possible for me to get one log file for each of my rails application. That would be desirable for my situation.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 5):

@cite's answer covers one option for distinguishing the apps. However, the syslog message framing actually has 2 fields that make it even easier: `hostname` and `tag` (more commonly known and used as program name).

`hostname` is set by the system syslog daemon before it forwards the message to a centralized server. It will be the same for all apps on the same system but may be handy as you grow past 1 server.

The more interesting one is `tag`. Your app defines `tag` when it instantiates `SyslogLogger`. For example:

```
SyslogLogger.new('app1')
```

The logger class will send to the system syslogd as `app1`, and that appear in both the local log file and any remote syslog destinations (without needing to modify the log message itself). The default is `rails`. All modern syslog daemons can filter based on `tag`; see `program()` for syslog-ng and `$programname` for rsyslog.

Also, it's worth noting that `SyslogLogger` is basically wrapping the C `openlog()` and `syslog()` functions, so basically all post-log configuration happens on the system daemon. Generally that's desirable, but sometimes you may want your Rails app to log directly to a specific destination (like to simplify automated deployment, change attributes not allowed by `syslog()`, or run in environments without access to the system daemon).

We ran into a couple of those cases and made a drop-in `Logger` replacement that generates the UDP packets itself. The `remote_syslog_logger` gem is [on GitHub](https://github.com/papertrail/remote_syslog_logger).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, by default, almost all Unix `syslogds` will write messages given in the `user` or `local*` facility in the same file. However, every `syslogd` I know will allow you to specify logfiles on a per-facility basis, so you can have your first application log to `local1.*`, second one to `local2.*` and so on.

Furthermore, newer syslog daemons like `syslog-ng` allow for splitting messages to different files by evaluating the message against a regular expression (write log strings which have `railsapp_1` in them to `/var/log/railsapp_1.log` and so on).

So, configure your `syslogd` appropriately and you are done (the gory details of changing that configuration should be asked on [serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/) if your system's man pages don't help you doing it.)