# How to view error messages from ruby CGI app on remote server?

Tags: ruby, apache, cgi, error-reporting

I have written a Ruby (not Rails) app which generates web pages. The script is installed on a linux web server and is called up by apache using CGI in response to HTTP requests. Pretty standard stuff.

When I am running it on my own computer I look at the apache error log to see the ruby error messages.

However, on the host that I use I have no access to the apache error_log. Therefore I am presently unable to see the error messages when my script hits a problem. Usually just a blank page or an apache error page.

I have ssh access to the host.

Is there a way to easily see the error messages and other log output?

Answer (score 1):

Multiple solutions here.

1. Redirect logs to syslog (assuming you have access to it). Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445118/using-syslog-in-rails-application)
2. Analyze Rails application logs (don't be confused by http logs in Apache) in your_app_dir/logs

Comment: Thankyou. My app is Ruby but not Rails however. In terms of redirecting logs, I tried the ErrorLog directive but apache wouldn't accept it, presumably it is a system setting. I am now thinking of making a wrapper script for the ruby executable to do the redirecting.

Comment: You should consider switching to Rails, you'll get a lot of functionality that you are looking for. Considering you are doing web development of course.