# Rails logger.error not showing up in SysLog

Tags: ruby-on-rails, syslog, syslog-ng

I have a question on how to configure correctly to get rails `logger.error` message showing up in `SysLog`. We used `SyslogLogger gem`.  In our `Syslog config`, we have filter like this:

```
if $programname == 'rails' and ($syslogseverity-text == 'emerg') then  @somehost                   

if $programname == 'rails' and ($syslogseverity-text == 'alert') then  @somehost                      

if $programname == 'rails' and ($syslogseverity-text == 'crit') then  @somehost                      

if $programname == 'rails' and ($syslogseverity-text == 'err') then @somehost                        

if $programname == 'rails' and ($syslogseverity-text == 'warn') then @somehost

if $programname == 'rails' then                         ~
```

When there is exception or fatal error, the log of stack trace will be showing up.  However, any statements that we use `logger.error` to log them are not showing up.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you need to comment out `#config.logger` in `config/environments/production.rb`.

After that, you can set `config.logger = SyslogLogger.new` or for a distributed setup `config.logger = SyslogLogger.new "myApp"`.

You can check out this [blog post](https://bowerstudios.com/node/688) or this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445118/using-syslog-in-rails-application?rq=1) for more information.

Comment: That is not the issue. We have that configure correctly in production.rb. The issue is how to set syslog filter correctly. Exception in rails show up in syslog.  It is just logger.error didn't show up